# <a href onClick> if function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't really know how to approach this if statement. I want to open the side menu on click, and close it on click again. This is the code I have for opening and closing:

```
<script>

    /* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}

</script>
```

I've tried using if statement, but I am not sure how to define "if a href is equal to open, then close".

This is a href:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="up" onClick="openNav()" >Menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

I also tired to use toggle jQuery, but the link didn't react.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#up").click(function(){
        $("#mySidenav").toggle();
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or code snippet with what you've tried - we can't guess your html structure to offer better solutions

Comment: I've tried toggle, which didn't work. I see no point adding that to a fiddle. All the needed html is here I belive.

Comment: I need to confirm that u have included the jquery library file in your page.=> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Filip5 In the first try you're setting the sideNav width to 0, in the second you're trying to use toggle which toggles the display attribute - you are not being clear which is why I asked - obviously you haven't given all the html, in fact any relating to sideNav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#up").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#mySidenav").toggle()
      });
});
```

```css
#mySideNav {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySidenav">
  my side nav
</div>
<button id="up">toggle</button>
```

Comment: I had to add the original script to it:

 
    /* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}

Now, I just need to solve the transition.

Answer (score 0):

You can call inline `javascript` function like that:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:openNav();" id=""  >Menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello there is a little problem that i can see in your jquery code.
when you are click on a element you should firstly remove the default using.
e.preventDefault()

the code become

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#up").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
        $("#mySidenav").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating two functions for closing and opening nav. You can toggle class and handle show/hide using CSS. 
In this way, you will increase page performance and will handle everything in CSS rather than in JS.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var nav = document.querySelector('nav');

btn.addEventListener('click', toggleNav);

function toggleNav() {
  nav.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transform: translateX(-1000%);
  transition: all 0.7s;
}

nav.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  This is your nav
</nav>

<button>
Show/Hide Nav
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

in openNav, change the binding click function to closeNav. in closeNav, change the binding click function to openNav. it means keep the binding function change while the Nav changed